# What does the forecast package show error?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

```
ARIMA_Modelb <- Arima(bankura_ts, order = c(0,0,1), 
                      seasonal = c(2,0,2))
ETS_Modelb <- ets(bankura_ts, damped = TRUE, model = "AZN")

#ARIMA Model Forecast
autoplot(forecast(ARIMA_Modelb, h=72)) + theme_bw() + 
  ylab("Rainfall") + xlab("Datetime") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%b - %Y', 
               breaks = '5 year', minor_breaks = '6 month') +
  theme_bw() + ggtitle("Bankura Rainfall Forecast 2021-2026 
  ARIMA Model")
#ETS Model Forecast
autoplot(forecast(ETS_Modelb, h=72)) + theme_bw() + 
  ylab("Rainfall") + xlab("Datetime") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%b - %Y', breaks = '5 year', 
               minor_breaks = '6 month') +
  theme_bw() + ggtitle("Bankura Rainfall Forecast 2021-2026 
  ETS Model")
```

The output shows some error in the forecast function:
`Error in forecast(fit1, h = 12) :  argument "M" is missing, with no default`

I tried reinstalling the forecast package to no avail and the same error is shown when using other codes

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*, namely adding sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Make sure that you're using `forecast()` from the forecast package. Try replacing `forecast()` with `forecast::forecast()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. the forecast::forecast() function was successful